# How to make IPv6 static routes persistent on CentOS?

Tags: centos, ipv6

Static routes are forgotten once the network service is restarted. However, IPv4 static routes can be made persistent by adding them to `/etc/sysconfig/static_routes`. This file is read by the network service when (re)starting and the static routes are added to the routing table.

This is the relevant code from `/etc/init.d/network`

```
# Add non interface-specific static-routes.
if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/static-routes ]; then
    grep "^any" /etc/sysconfig/static-routes | while read ignore args ; do
        /sbin/route add -$args
    done
fi
```

However, no such file seems to exist for IPv6 static routes, which are lost upon network restart. Is editing the `/etc/init.d/network` script the only way? (So that it reads from a manually created file storing IPv6 routes and adds them to routing table when network (re)starts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't run CentOS or Red Hat to check, but some documentation point to `/etc/sysconfig/static-routes-ipv6`. Complete documentation is available at http://www.deepspace6.net/projects/initscripts-ipv6.html This is the example given:

```
#Device   IPv6 network to route   IPv6 gateway address
eth0      fec0:0:0:2::/64         fec0:0:0:1:0:0:0:20
eth0      2000::/3                3ffe:ffff:0000:f102:0:0:0:1
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I add route to IPv6 host instead of network?

Comment: Again, I don't have the resources to test it, but my first guess would be to specify only the interface name and a /128 address: `eth0 fd42:0:0:2::1/128`

Comment: I looked at the shell scripts called from the network service. And eventually the 'ip' command is called to add the routes. It so happens that even if you mention /128, this command adds the route as a UG and not UGH. Well thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `route6-{interface}` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`? It should work like `route-{interface}` does for ipv4